# Fock space and the GNS construction of a free field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, wightman-fields

Let's consider a scalar field obeying Wightman's axioms. In the Wightman reconstruction theorem, we can reconstruct the Hilbert space by starting with the algebra
$\mathcal{A} = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathscr{S}(M^n)$ (here $M$ is Minkowski space and $\mathscr{S}(M)$ is the Schwartz space on it). We then define
$\eta: \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{C}$ as the unique linear functional which extends the Wightman distributions to $\mathcal{A}$
(i.e. $\eta(f_1 \otimes \dots \otimes f_n) = W(f_1, \dots, f_n)$.
Then we find the kernel $J = \{f \in \mathcal{A} | \eta(f, f) = 0\}$, and out Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is the completion of the factor space $\mathcal{A} / J$.

Now, if we have a free scalar field, we know that $\mathcal{H}$ is also Fock space,
$\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C} + \bigoplus \mathcal{H}_1^{\otimes n}$ where $\mathcal{H}_1$ is the single particle space.

Can we write explicitly a formula that matches elements of the Fock space with equivalence classes of the factor space? We can do it for the single-particle space
– with the equivalence classes of single-variable functions:
$\mathcal{H}_1 = \{[f]_J | f \in \mathscr{S}(M)$ (at least I think that's right?).

But if we have an element of the $n$-particle space
$[f_1] \otimes \dots \otimes [f_n]$ can we tell which equivalence class it corresponds to (this tensor product, unfortunately, is different from the algebra product)?